# Кэширование результатов запроса к БД ?

Tags: php, база-данных

Привет всем. У меня на сайте будет такая реализация, что все имена пунктов меню и основные статические текстовые элементы находятся в базе данных (мультиязычный интерфейс). Стало быть, при каждом обновлении страницы и при переходах по другим страницам сайта, каждый раз эти статические  данные будут извлекаться из БД. Кончено, это совершенно лишние действия и нагрузка на сервер. Краем уха слышал про кэширование, но не знаю - это то, что мне нужно? Кто знаком с такого рода проблемой, пожалуйста, подскажите правильных ход или адрес ресурса, где можно ознакомиться с решением вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Про кэш вы верно подумали, но я бы советовал глянуть вам в сторону файлов с локализацией, и реализовать это переменными внутри php.

если уже завязались с бд(кстати стоило ее указать), то вот по теме

```
1) Кэш на стороне БД(MySQL) http://webew.ru/articles/1041.webew
2) Кэш на стороне пхп http://habrahabr.ru/qa/23126/
```

Comment: Еще момент по кэшу, если он вам очень интересен посмотрите на реализацию оного в phpbb, работаю с данным движком и оч нравится тамошняя реализация кэша, там кэшируется все, запросы, стили, целые странички....

Comment: Все менюшки, параметры сайта(title,description) решил прописать в файлах и подключать их. Статьи и комменты - в mysql

Comment: Хорошее решение как показует время и чужие наработки)

Comment: Просто ВООБЩЕ не умею пользоваться движками, даже простейший wordpress вывел меня из себя. Поэтому предпочитаю все делать сам )))

Comment: Меня тоже выводили из себя) потом решился разобратся и втянуло) начинал с phpnuke, пробовал и вордпрес и джумлу, остановился на phpbb(на нем можно сделать что угодно а не только форум)...

Comment: @ToRcH565, приму к сведению phpbb.

Answer (score 0):

По файлам можно распихать используя функцию serialize

Или готовый html в файл сохранять, а потом инклюдить

Answer (score -2):

храни лучше в сессиях. например:

```
в файле настроек:  
$_SESSION['lang']='ru'

в остальных файлах:
if($_SESSION['lang']=='ru') echo "Привет!"; else echo "Hello!";
```

Comment: В сессиях у меня и так хранится язык, но в базе данных  - пункты меню . Например, в таблице site_engine есть два поля - ru_title и en_title. Исходя из сессионной переменной lang будут выбираться записи на соответственном языке. Вопрос в том, что в этом случае придется тормошить базу данных при каждом обновлении страницы!

Comment: храните в сессиях все пункты меню.

Comment: Меня хостингер не расстреляет за оккупацию его ресурсов? over 9000 меню и подменю плюс все тестовые элементы футера и т.д! К тому же расчет идет на будущую посещаемость в 1000 - 3000 посетителей в сутки.

Comment: Это как минимум глупо. как максимум менее оптимально чем в бд хранить.и каждый пользователь =+1 сессия(не жирно ли для локали?)

Comment: значит куки.

Comment: не знаю, может правда создать два файла - english.php и russian.php с соответствующими массивами данных и подключать их в соответствии с выбранным языком?

Comment: Куки еще худший вариант нежели сессия, хотябы потому что каждый раз гоняется от клиента к серверу(с каждым запросом).